# C# Send data with method POST to API

Tags: c#, json, api, vsto

Dont know what i doing wrong, need to fill database with datas from my VSTO Outlook Addin.

`jObjectbody.Add( new { mail_from = FromEmailAddress });` `mail_from` is name of column in database, `FromEmailAddress` is value from my Outlook Addin

How to send to API `https://my.address.com/insertData` correctly ?

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://my.address.com/");

JObject jObjectbody = new JObject();
jObjectbody.Add( new { mail_from = FromEmailAddress });

RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("insertData", Method.POST);
restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
restRequest.AddParameter("text/html", jObjectbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

error : `` Could not determine JSON object type for type <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]. ``

If i try this in Postman (POST->Body->raw->JSON) data are strored in database, except dont use `value` just data.

```
{
"mail_from":"email@email.com"
}
```

thanks for any clue achieve success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `restRequest.AddJsonBody(jObjectbody);` instead of `AddParameter` (which I believe adds a query string).

See the [RestSharp AddJsonBody](https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#addjsonbody) docs. They also mention to **not** use some sort of `JObject` as it wont work, so you will probably need to update your type as well.

The below might work for you:

```cs
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://my.address.com/");

var body = new { mail_from = "email@me.com" };

RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("insertData", Method.POST);
restRequest.AddJsonBody(body);

IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

// extra points for calling async overload instead
//var asyncResponse = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(restRequest);
```